# Комментарии к запоздалым ответам

Tags: обсуждение

При проверке запоздалых ответов и первых постов часто сталкиваюсь с [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35797/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/93262#93262) ситуацией: ответ низкого качества от новичка, являющийся единственным постом данного пользователя. При этом ответу может быть несколько месяцев или лет, а автор с момента публикации ответа ни разу на сайте не появлялся. Есть ли смысл оставлять комментарии с предложениями по улучшению ответа (в надежде, что другие пользователи, увидев такой комментарий, не станут плодить подобные ответы), либо стоит молча рекомендовать ответ к удалению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит смотреть в первую очередь на качество ответа. Если видно, что автор скорее всего не в состоянии улучшить его, то можно удалять в не зависимости от даты публикации. Сообщения от пользователей, которые с большой вероятностью смогут улучшить публикуемое содержимое, лучше сопровождать комментарием.

Беря во внимание, что это ошибка процессов на ХэшКоде, то надеюсь, как верно заметил @Athari, подобных ситуаций в будущем возникать не должно.

Answer (score 3):

Это временная проблема и напрямую связана с переездом. Движок сайта решил, что в ревью "запоздалых ответов" должны попадать все ответы, которые отдалены от написания вопроса по времени, без оглядки на то, как давно был отправлен ответ.

В нормальных условиях этого происходить не должно. Очередь ревью не должна разрастаться, поэтому все комментарии будут своевременными.

В очереди запоздалых ответов на данный момент чуть более сотни постов. Можно, конечно, задуматься над оптимальным поведением в этом случае, но статистически это не имеет значения: плюс-минус 0.2% постов ничего не решают.

Я бы сказал, что оставлять комментарии к постам большой давности смысла большого нет. Более того, далеко не всегда необходимо оставлять комментарии и к свежим ответам. Не зря первым пунктом идёт вариант "комментарии не нужны".

Answer (score 2):

В **такой** ситуации я бы переносил ответ в комментарий (кстати, есть ли такая возможность у кого-то, кроме самого автора ответа и админов?).

С такими ответами связан один недочет, насколько я понимаю: для того, чтобы писать комментарии, нужен рейтинг выше, чем для написания ответов. Вот народ и пишет подобные "ответы".

Comment: Скорее всего, такая возможность (если она есть в движке SO) есть только у модераторов. У меня есть все привилегии, которые можно получить за рейтинг, но превращать ответы в комментарии я не могу.

Comment: @fori1ton Подтверждаю, что перенос ответа в комментарий возможен, но только для модераторов. Пользователь может предложить перенос   модератору путём "тревога->другое".  Если, конечно, там имеется хоть что-то стоящее; в противном случае лучше просто удалить.

Comment: Это не баг, а фича, что называется. От новичков ожидают ответов на вопросы, которые не требуют долгого расковыривания деталей в комментариях (обычно из-за некачественного вопроса). Комментарии в ревью не попадают, поэтому мусор от новичков, будь разрешены комментарии, никогда бы не удалялся. А так есть возможность следить за чистотой сайта, пусть при этом у новичков и теряется возможность отвечать на некачественные вопросы — невелика потеря. Да и 50 репы получить труда не составляет.

Comment: @Athari фича довольно дурацкая, надо сказать. Вот типичный сценарий: новичок регистрируется для того чтобы задать вопрос, задает его, ему отвечают, у новичка возникают уточняющие вопросы. Как их ему задать? А никак, комментарии-то недоступны. Что же, перед тем как задавать свой вопрос, человек должен побегать репу насобирать? Вот и пишут "ответы". То же самое и с запоздалыми ответами: человек может и хочет сперва оставить комментарий, система ему не разрешает и он пишет "ответ".

Comment: @andreycha Комментировать в рамках *своего* поста юзеры могут с любой репутацией. Также, если 1-репового юзера *пригласить* в чат, то он сможет пользоваться и чатом.

Comment: @Athari аа, понял. Ну тогда эта фича аффектит только тех, кто хочет прокомментировать чужие вопросы, не набрав нужной репы. И согласен, что после того как разгребем текущую очередь, поток будет не такой большой.

Comment: @Athari, А как *приглашать* в чат? Последний раз когда я пробоавал, максимум чего получилось достичь, это доступ к чату только на чтения для приглашённого пользователя (которые до этого о StackExchange не знал). Там есть кнопка типа "дать доступ этому пользователю к этой комнате чата", но она только для модераторов вроде.